# One big Rails application vs separate application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on one big project. Now we need to add new functionality: scheduler managment.
It's not a main task of application, but it is quite complicated part of it.

Is it good idea to extract it as a separate application?

It will share some data (users and some other personalities) and it will use the same database.

The main reason I want to do it is to simplify main application.

I understand, that it is mayby too wide question. But maybe you can share your expirience of developing this kind of applications and maybe there are any articles I can read and world-wide best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While others have mentioned some of the benefits of separating the applications, I'll touch on a couple of reasons why you might NOT want to separate the code.

1. You're going to need to maintain a single set of tests, especially if both applications are sharing the same database.  If you don't do this, it's hard to predict when changing one application would break the other, especially if the applications start to need different things out of the database.
2. The two applications are obviously going to have a lot of overlap (users, for example).  Separating into two applications could potentially force you to duplicate code, since rails by default has some pretty specific ideas about how a rails application should be structured.  If your applications are sharing certain views, for example, what will you do to coordinate change in both applications when one application wants to modify the view?

Neither of these is insurmountable, but rails is easiest to develop when you follow rails conventions.  As you begin to deviate, you end up having to do more work.  Also, don't take either of these points as invalidating the other answers here, but merely counterpoints that you need to think about.

Comment: Good answer, Thanks a lot! I was thinking about benefits and didn't think about negatives

Answer (score 3):

When you can use the functionality in other projects too, then I would separate it.
Maybe you can create a rails engine to share it easily between projects.

Answer (score 3):

Consider asking yourself "What about re-usability?"  Is the new scheduling functionality likely to be re-usable in another context with another application?  If the answer is "yes," then perhaps making the scheduling management more modular in design will save you time in the future.  If the answer is "no," then I would think you have more leeway in how tightly you integrate scheduling management with your existing app.

The practical difference here would be writing generalized scheduling management functionality that has assignable tables and methods upon which to act versus more 'hard coding' it with the data/code scheme of your 'onebig project.'

hth -

Perry

Comment: but what if there is a ton of controllers and models in my application? isn't it a reason to redesign my app and maybe separate some parts?

Comment: Hard to know, floor.  Deciding how modular your code should be is an art, not a science.  I expect there are many 'correct' answers regarding how you should proceed here.  When to go 'more modular' or 'less modular' probably depends on other things too, like how many programmers may be helping, what are their skill sets, is the new functionality helpful and unique enough to be an app by itself, to name a few.

Comment: and... maybe think about how stable your current 'big project' (BP) is too.  If the functionality needs served by BP are changing over time, this is a good reason to make thing more modular too.

Comment: It is refactored time by time, but now I am missing sometimes in all that count of files in the project.

Answer (score 2):

Adding management-tools into a web-app often complicate deployment, is my experience. Especially when the use of your application grows, and you need to performance-tune it, dragging along a huge "backend" may be problematic.

For sake of deploy-, scale- and test-ability, I prefer my applications to be small and focused. Sometimes it even pays off to have the entire admin-enviroment over REST-XML-services.

But as other answers point out: this is more a "it depends" solution. These are my €0.02.